# Can't access parent form's button properties through user control form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have parent form called MainBackground and a user control named LoginUI. LoginUI is docked into the MainBackground.

I need to change enability of a button (InfoButton) located in parent form to "true" when user clicks on the button "Log in" in the control form.

But I can't access the parent button's properties.

Control form's button clicking event code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainBackground.infoButton.Enabled = true;    
        }
```

I tried solving it with parent controls, but still it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Umm... do you really expect us to understand what you mean by "can't access the button at all?" Kindly add the essential details.

Comment: I meant that I could not access InfoButton's properties from user control. Sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: Please provide more details regrading question. Possibly add the screen shot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access `MainBackground.infoButton` from `LoginUI` because infoButton is not [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static).

to solve this you could inject MainBackground trough a property like the example below

```
public partial class LoginUI : UserControl
{
    public MainBackground MainBackground { get; set; }  
    ...
}
```

in `MainBackground` you should initalize your `LoginUI.MainBackground` propery

```
loginUI1.MainBackground = this;
```

Make sure to make `infoButton` public
by setting the **modifiers** property to `public`

Now you can access `MainBackground.loginUI1`

```
private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MainBackground.InfoButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: infoButton does not have to be static. You just need a public property like in this answer, that has nothing to do with static

Answer (score 0):

The method described in your question of Enabling the `MainBackground` forms `InfoButton` when the `Login` button is pressed is a common action. However, instead of directly binding the two items where the LoginUI Control is now forever bound to the MainBackground Form, you should de-couple the two by using Events.

The LoginUI Control should publish an event, perhaps called, `LoginClicked`. The MainBackground form can then subscribe to this event and execute whatever actions are required when the Login button is clicked.

In the LoginUI Control, declare an event:

```
    public event EventHandler LoginClicked;
```

And, raise it whenever the Login button is pressed:

```
    private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnLoginClicked(EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    protected virtual void OnLoginClicked(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = LoginClicked;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
```

Finally, in the MainBackground form class, subscribe to the LoginClicked event

```
    loginUI.LoginClicked += this.loginUI_LoginClicked;
```

Handle the LoginClicked event like this:

```
    private void loginUI_LoginClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InfoButton.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: That seems like a more elegant solution. Thanks! I'll certaintly check it out!